# I need to compare %01[1 02813]$ which is the output from my weighing scale with TCP IP Connection Protocol

Tags: python, lua

When i connect to 192.168.1.10:1001 port and send command %01R$$ then i get some value i.e. %01[1 02813]$
which i then splice and get it into one single variable Call Actual Weight . (Please Refer the photo 1 & 2 Attached below)

[image: Blocky Diagram for the logic explained above]

[image: Debugging Tool Description]

i am getting error "Attempt to compare Number with String"

What is the way forward please help as it is a on going project for robotics sorting using weighing scale.
Thank you.

I tried Getting it into another variable which take a number as input and tried converting but no success so far.

This is the program which was generated in the backend:

2 Files Generated :

global.lua

```css
Pre_Data = ''
Post_Data = ''
Weight = 0
Data_Char = 0
Actual_Weight = 0
WEIGHT_WEIGHT_WEIGHT = 0 
function Get_Weight()
resultOpen1,socket1 = TCPCreate(false, '192.168.1.10', 1001)
  if resultOpen1 == 0 then
      print("Create TCP Client Success!")
  else
      print("Create TCP Client failed, code:", resultOpen1)
  end
  resultOpen1 = TCPStart(socket1, 0)
  if resultOpen1 == 0 then
      print("Connect TCP Server Success!")
  else
      print("Connect TCP Server failed, code:", resultOpen1)
  end
  print((resultOpen1))
resultWrite1 = TCPWrite(socket1, '%01R$$')
resultRead1,Pre_Data = TCPRead(socket1, 0, 'string')
Pre_Data = Pre_Data.buf
resultRead1,Post_Data = TCPRead(socket1, 0, 'string')
Post_Data = Post_Data.buf
Weight = Pre_Data..Post_Data
print(Weight)
Data_Char = 7
for count = 1, 5 do
  Actual_Weight = Actual_Weight..(string.sub(Weight, Data_Char ,Data_Char))
  Data_Char = Data_Char + 1
  Sleep(50)
end
print(Actual_Weight)
end
```

```html
Get_Weight( )
WEIGHT_WEIGHT_WEIGHT = Actual_Weight
Sync()
if WEIGHT_WEIGHT_WEIGHT>280 then
  MovJ((P1))
else
  MovJ((P2))
end
```

src0.lua

Pre_Data = '' Post_Data = '' Weight = 0 Data_Char = 0 Actual_Weight = 0 WEIGHT_WEIGHT_WEIGHT = 0  function Get_Weight() resultOpen1,socket1
= TCPCreate(false, '192.168.1.10', 1001)   if resultOpen1 == 0 then
print("Create TCP Client Success!")   else
print("Create TCP Client failed, code:", resultOpen1)   end   resultOpen1 = TCPStart(socket1, 0)   if resultOpen1 == 0 then
print("Connect TCP Server Success!")   else
print("Connect TCP Server failed, code:", resultOpen1)   end   print((resultOpen1)) resultWrite1 = TCPWrite(socket1, '%01R$$') resultRead1,Pre_Data = TCPRead(socket1, 0, 'string') Pre_Data = Pre_Data.buf resultRead1,Post_Data = TCPRead(socket1, 0, 'string') Post_Data = Post_Data.buf Weight = Pre_Data..Post_Data print(Weight) Data_Char = 7 for count = 1, 5 do   Actual_Weight = Actual_Weight..(string.sub(Weight, Data_Char ,Data_Char))   Data_Char
= Data_Char + 1   Sleep(50) end print(Actual_Weight) end

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible code snipped (as code block - put it between those ``` and not as picture)

Comment: Why is this tagged for Python? I see no Python code

Comment: The backend can also be coded in python hence the tag